# How should I change this Shuffle method to make the shuffle function work

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a music app using android studio and currently am working on my shuffle function. However when i test out my shuffle function, after the first song finish playing, the app just stops.

I hope i can get help and that the end result would be the shuffle function able to play the music that corresponds to the result of the RNG

```
public Song getShuffleSong(String currentSongid){
    Song ShuffleSong=null;
    Random song = new Random();
    for (int counter=0; counter< 10000;counter++){
        int x = song.nextInt(3);
        String tempSongid = allsongs[x].getid();
        if (tempSongid.equals(currentSongid)) {
            if (x == 0) {
                ShuffleSong = allsongs[0];
                break;
            }
            if (x == 1) {
                ShuffleSong = allsongs[1];
                break;
            }
            if (x == 2) {
                ShuffleSong = allsongs[2];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return ShuffleSong;
}
```

Comment: If there is any problem with the indentation in the code posted on top i just want to point out that it it just an accident and it is not the problem.

Comment: Please add the errors from the studio's logger

Comment: You don't have an array `allsongs` so you can't access `allsongs[x]`. Also, why not just use shuffle methods already included in Java like `Collections.shuffle(playlist)` or something like that.

Comment: @O95 I actually have an array but the whole code was too long that I didnt include it, but thank you for suggesting the collection.shuffle function. Is it possible for you to teach me how to use it